# Charge present at the centroid of equilateral triangle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

Three equal charges +Q each are placed on the vertices of an equilateral triangle.  A charge +q is initially placed at the centre of the triangle.  If this charge (+q) is slightly displaced towards a vertex and left free.

**What will be its motion?**

My working:

Initially its in equilibrium and when its displaced to one end, charges far from it will exert lesser repulsive force and the vertex charge will exert more force since it went closer to it. Hence it goes back to its original position and does SHM.

**Am I correct?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the Earnshaw's theorem might make such motion unstable. You may consider a similar problem: a positive charge between two positive charges. All your reasoning seems applicable there, but it is intuitively obvious that the motion will be unstable.

Comment: What do you mean by unstable? It won't be SHM then?

Comment: Is it oscillatory motion then?

Comment: @Mixcels: Imagine a ball "oscillating" on a saddle: its motion will be unstable with respect to ball motion orthogonal to its original trajectory, so the ball will eventually fall from the saddle. So the motion of your charge will be unstable with respect to its motion in the direction orthogonal to its displacement from the center of the triangle. So the charge will probably be driven outside of the triangle, and its motion will not be periodical.

Comment: I dont understand why would it go off when repulsive force is pushing it back to the centre.

Comment: @Mixcels: because the charge's motion will be unstable with respect to displacements in the transverse direction, however small. There is a reason it is difficult, to say the least, to balance an egg on its narrow end.

Comment: In the example you provided in your answer, why would the motion be unstable?

Comment: And why would the charge have unstable motion in the direction perpendicular to its displacement? The net force in that direction zero.

Comment: Hello..you there?

Comment: @Mixcels: I don' t know how to explain it. Looks like you don't quite know what stable/unstable equilibrium is. Maybe you should look here first: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_equilibrium

Comment: I do know about stable and unstable equilibrium. My question is, why doesn't the charge do periodic motion. Once its dispaced towards a vertex, it will pe pushed back. It will cross the initial point and then go over the other side and stop again. So isnt this periodic motion?

Comment: @Mixcels: You chose one direction in which motion is stable, but for the equilibrium to be stable, motion must be stable in any direction. According to the Earnshaw theorem, there is a direction in which motion is not stable in your case, for example, out-of-plane motion.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. You are correct that its not stable motion. But can I call it periodic motion in that specific direction?

Comment: @Mixcels: Maybe you can under some exotic definitions, but not in my book: in reality, there will be no periodic motion, the charge will get out of plane in no time due to instability.